# Python Selenium: Iteration Error

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webdriver, iteration

I'm trying to download all xml files from a webpage. The process requires locating xml file download link one after the other, and once such a download link is clicked it leads to a form which needs to be submitted for the download to begin. The issue I'm facing lies in the iteration of these loops, once the first file is downloaded from the webpage I receive an error:

"selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of  stale: either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed"

The "97081 data-extension xml" is the 2nd downloadable file in the iteration. I've hereby attached the code, any suggestions to rectify this will be much appreciated.

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "F:\Projects\Poli_Map\DatG_Py_Dat")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/xml")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

driver.get('https://data.gov.in/catalog/variety-wise-daily-market-prices-data-cauliflower')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

allelements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[text()='xml']")

for element in allelements:
    element.click()
    class FormPage(object):
        def fill_form(self, data):
            driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('edit-download-reasons-non-commercial').click()")
            driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('edit-reasons-d-rd').click()")
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "name_d"]').send_keys(data['name_d'])
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "mail_d"]').send_keys(data['mail_d'])
            return self

        def submit(self):
            driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('edit-submit').click()")

    data = {
        'name_d': 'xyz',
        'mail_d': 'xyz@outlook.com',
    }
    time.sleep(5)
    FormPage().fill_form(data).submit()

    time.sleep(5)
    window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
    driver.switch_to_window(window_before)
    driver.back()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for you, no need to submit any fields.

You need to get the ID in the class field in the bottom of this picture (here for instance its 962721)

[image]

Then, use this URL like so :
**https://data.gov.in/node/962721/download**

This was found just doing a bit of "reverse-engineering". When you do web scraping, always have a look at the .js files and at your networking tab to see all the requests made.